# Looping in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am making a latin square board puzzle and I'm making the code to open up a text file and store the data in a dictionary. However when I loop through the code its printing out repetitively.
For example in my text document i have

```
ABC
CAB
BCA
```

When i run my code i want the output to be that however i get

```
ABC
ABCCAB
ABCCABBCA
```

My current code is:

```
d={}
while True:
    try:
        filename=input("Enter the name of the file to open: ") + ".txt"
        with open(filename,"r") as f:
            for line in f:
                splitLine=line.split()
                d[splitLine[0]]=splitLine[1:]
                #print(line, end="")
                print(d)
            break

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File name does not exist; please try again")
```

What exactly do I need to do to stop printing out the above line. I believe its to do with the:

```
d[splitLine[0]]=splitLine[1:]
```

But i'm not sure how to tackle this issue

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want d to look like?

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary for a game board rather than a 2D list?

Comment: @m_callens Eh i'm only using what im familiar with. Should i make it into a list and then print it out?

Comment: @Garrett R well i want it to print out the same way its stored in the text file, so in a plain way ABC then new row CAB and then new row BCA

Comment: @Xrin : You are storing it as a dictionary though. So, if you remove the print(d) in your code and place it after all the lines, you'll get the dictionary as such without it getting repeated. But you'll get pairs of values.

Comment: @Aiyoyo Indeed, if i place it after all the lines of code it prints out as
`{'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['C', 'A'], 'C': ['A', 'B']}`
So why is it exactly that there is the [B,C] in a list but the A isnt? But regardless the problem isnt solved because it wont be printing in the correct format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, a list is probably a better choice for your gameboard. You can do that like this:

```
d = []
while True:
    try:
        filename = 'foo.txt'
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                d.append(list(line.strip()))
            break

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File name does not exist; please try again")

print(d)

for line in d:
    print(''.join(line))
```

This outputs:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['C', 'A', 'B'], ['B', 'C', 'A']]
ABC
CAB
BCA
```

The for-loop prints it out exactly as you read it in

Comment: Thank you; could you explain the `d.append(list(line.strip()))` part please? I understand that the append adds a list (line) to the end of list "d"; but what exactly is the strip doing?

Comment: When you read in each line in the file, there's a newline at the end of the line. Calling `list('ABC\n')` gives `['A', 'B', 'C', '\n']`. To get rid of the newline, you use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) to remove the extra whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

It makes much more sense to store your board in a 2-dimensional list:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    board = [list(line) for line in f.read().splitlines()]

for row in board:
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
['C', 'A', 'B']
['B', 'C', 'A']
```

It is then possible to pick a value based on its coordinates:

```
board[0][0] # top left 'A'
board[2][2] # bottom right 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in pointing out the problem.

You need to empty out the variable:

```
d
```

every time you loop.

Example:

```
d={}
while True:
    try:
        filename=input("Enter the name of the file to open: ") + ".txt"
        with open(filename,"r") as f:
            for line in f:
                splitLine=line.split()
                d[splitLine[0]]=splitLine[1:]
                print(line, end="")
                d={}
            break

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File name does not exist; please try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be better just storing it as a list (or list of lists) instead of making it a dictionary.

```
d=[]
while True:
    try:
        #filename=input("Enter the name of the file to open: ") + ".txt"
        with open("file.txt","r") as f:
            for line in f:
                splitLine=line.split()
                d.extend(splitLine)
                #print(line, end="")

            break

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File name does not exist; please try again")

for elem in d:
        print elem
```

If you use a list structure like this and then finally use a loop to go through all the elements, you'll get the output that you desired.

Output :

```
ABC
CAB
BCA
```